# Typescript paths not resolving when running jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, tsconfig, ts-jest

Attempting to [convert this project](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator) over to jest using [these instructions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/testing/jest.html).  I have everything working except for the files that use the `paths` configuration:

```
"paths": {
      "@fs/*": ["./src/*"], 
      "@test/*": ["./test/*"]
    }
```

It looks as if when the tests are run the import statements do not resolve and this is logged:

```
Cannot find module '@fs/container/validation/ValidationContext' from 'Core.spec.ts'

  1 | import { ValidationOptions } from "@fs/container/validation/ValidationOptions";
> 2 | import { ValidationContext } from "@fs/container/validation/ValidationContext";
    | ^
  3 | import { ValidationContainer } from "@fs/container/validation/ValidationContainer";
  4 | 
  5 | import { Core1 } from "@test/core/Core1";

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/core/Core.spec.ts:2:1)
```

Is there a way to get jest/ts-jest include the `@paths` while resolving imports?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

jest can't honor tsconfig's path mapping as it's ts compiler time, so jest configuration should have corresponding [modulenamemapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) to resolve aliased paths.

Answer (score 70):

I wanted to resolve modules [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) starting with `~/` to my `<baseUrl>/<moduleName>`.

Thank to [OJ Kwon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52861763/802365) link I solved it with (give him point).

#### tsconfig.json

see [module-resolution path-mapping doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["*"]
    }
  },
}
```

#### jest config

Then we need to tell `jest` to resolve the paths too. It's done with the following config:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "~/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
},
```

Comment: It helped me a lot in my case my ts path was "@data/*": ["src/data/*"] then in my jest config i added: '@data/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/data/$1',

Comment: If you set `rootDir` to `src` then you don't need to remove `src` from here.

Answer (score 33):

Add jest.config.js on root project folder with the content below.

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
  coverageDirectory: '../coverage',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  testRegex: '.*\\.spec\\.ts$',
  transform: { '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest' },
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.(t|j)s'],
};
```

Also make sure that your `tsconfig.json` file has a `paths` field, like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ....,
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: what is ts-jest/utils?

Comment: `const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest')`.  See https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/#jest-config-with-helper

Comment: This is the best solution to keep your `tsconfig` path resolvers in sync with your Jest config.

Comment: No longer works

Comment: I had to add the `prefix` parameter to get it to work: `pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: "<rootDir>" })`.

Comment: A `baseUrl` should be took in account: `{ prefix: \`<rootDir>${compilerOptions.baseUrl}\` }`

Comment: Thank you adding the `modulePaths` is what solved it for me. I know it was something to do with the rootDir!

Answer (score 4):

Answer By @FranSanchis did fix the issue for me, I have just done a lot bit of changes to meet with 2023 jest changes

in **jest.config.js**

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  
  preset: 'ts-jest',
.
.
.
moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
}
```

And in tsconfig

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "paths": {
    "@/*": ["src/*"]
  }
}
```

**package.json** (for unit test)

```
"jest": {
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testRegex": "/test/.*\\.spec\\.ts$",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  }
}
```

**jest-e2e.json** (for e2e test)

```
{
  "rootDir": "../",
  "testRegex": "/test/.*\\.e2e-spec\\.ts$",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).